# Gameport to USB?

Tags: hardware

I have a [Microsoft SideWinder Game Pad (Part Number: 90873)](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sac=1&_nkw=Microsoft+Sidewinder+Game+Pad+-+90873) that I want to use with my Raspberry Pi [RetroPie](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/). I have the [pinout](http://pinouts.ru/Inputs/GameportPC_pinout.shtml) and want to replace the GamePort end with USB. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Transform-Your-15-Pin-%28Gameport%29-Microsoft-Sidewinder-Precision-Pro-Into-a-USB-Joystick)

```
GP1  --> USB Red  
GP4  --> USB Black  
GP10 --> USB Green  
GP14 --> USB White  
GP2  --> GP7
```

and I have power, but the Raspberry Pi won't recognize the controller, and it seems like there are a lot of connections missing. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Your linked instructions are for a Precision Pro joystick, not a Game Pad.

Comment: It's my understanding that GamePort is the standard that a bunch of controllers follow. Precision Pro and SideWinder both use the GamePort connector, so should have the same pinout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 'hack' will only work on the Sidewinder Precision Pro joystick. From WikiPedia:

> with the widespread introduction of USB in consumer computers shortly after the Precision Pro was released, Microsoft soon re-released the joystick in a USB-compatible form (joysticks labeled as Part No. X03-57540, Product I.D. 85791-...[8]). The revised joystick still featured a gameport connector but had additional circuitry for interfacing with USB, and was bundled with a USB converter

I will not work with any other gameport device. You need to buy a "USB Gameport adapter."

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I'll look into a way of interfacing with Arduino. Or just buy a different controller lol.

Comment: @Thomas the GamePort is extremely simple; it looks like you could emulate it with 4 GPIO (digital) and 2 ADC (analog) inputs. If you can get by with a D-pad, a little extra circuity could easily turn the two analog channels into 4 digital. Though it would be easier to just hack up an NES controller (requires no extra circuitry).

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm kinda just getting started. Do you have a link to where I could find more information on how to do the emulation?

Answer (score 2):

I Have modified several Microsoft Precision Pro Joysticks.
 The USB to Game port adaptor is a.F3U200-08inch made by Belkin and can be bought on Amazon for less than $10.00.
However here is the tricky part. You must make a "Jumper" wire using a small wire usually found on a "Wire tie". you have to "Jump the wire from Pins 2 to 7 **on the Joystick**. 
Strip only the part of the wire that will go over the pins. I used a very fine pair of Needle nose plyers for this operation.